# Scan 3 lines of string in C, without gets()

Tags: c

My homework is to write a simple encryption program. The code worked perfectly (examples are provided) in my online C compiler, but when I submitted this as a solution, it gave me error. I investigated and I think the code master doesn't like that I'm using `gets()`.
Input example

```
ZEBRASCDFGHIJKLMNOPQTUVWXY
FLEE AT ONCE WE ARE DISCOVERED
FLEE AT ONCE WE ARE DISCOVERED
Output should be
SIAA ZQ LKBA VA ZOA RFPBLUAOAR
SIAA ZQ LKBA VA ZOA RFPBLUAOAR
```

Now the code itself. I just want to substitute gets, tried many solutions already.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i, len1, len2, j;
char toenc1[27], toenc2[27], enc[27], alph[27] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
gets(enc);
gets(toenc1); // SUBSTITUTE THESE
gets(toenc2);
len1 = strlen(toenc1);
len2 = strlen(toenc2);
for (i = 0 ; i < len1 ; i ++){
    for (j = 0; j < 27 ; j++){
        if (toenc1[i] == alph[j]){
        toenc1[i] = enc[j]; 
        j=26;
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i ++){
    for (j = 0; j < 27 ; j++){
        if (toenc2[i] == alph[j]){
        toenc2[i] = enc[j]; 
        j=26;
        }
    }
}
printf("%s \n", toenc1);
printf("%s", toenc2);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `fgets()`, not `gets()`.

Comment: The input line `FLEE AT ONCE WE ARE DISCOVERED` cannot fit in a buffer of size 27, so your attempt to read that line with `gets` triggers undefined behavior.  You should *never* use `gets`

Comment: @Barmar I know it has been removed in C11, but why was `gets()` even part of the standard in the first place if it cannot be used safely at all?

Comment: @user16217248 because the original designers went for simplicity instead of safety.

Comment: C is inherently unsafe, and created by white-hats who did not realise that black-hats would interfere. They kept it simple, on the grounds that the programmers would know what they are doing. Previously, system designers had been using assembler.

Comment: @andromedstrain You failed to provide us with the error.

Comment: @Cheatah When I compile it in a linux terminal I get a warning about gets(), but I still can input data and get the answer. When I submit the solution I just get an error, it doesn't specify the problem.